# Creating lowpass filter in SciPy - understanding methods and units

Tags: python, scipy, filtering, signal-processing

I am trying to filter a noisy heart rate signal with python. Because heart rates should never be above about 220 beats per minute, I want to filter out all noise above 220 bpm. I converted 220/minute into 3.66666666 Hertz and then converted that Hertz to rad/s to get 23.0383461 rad/sec.

The sampling frequency of the chip that takes data is 30Hz so I converted that to rad/s to get 188.495559 rad/s.

After looking up some stuff online I found some functions for a bandpass filter that I wanted to make into a lowpass. [Here is the link the bandpass code](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/ButterworthBandpass), so I converted it to be this:

```
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter
from scipy.signal import freqs

def butter_lowpass(cutOff, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normalCutoff = cutOff / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, normalCutoff, btype='low', analog = True)
    return b, a

def butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutOff, fs, order=4):
    b, a = butter_lowpass(cutOff, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

cutOff = 23.1 #cutoff frequency in rad/s
fs = 188.495559 #sampling frequency in rad/s
order = 20 #order of filter

#print sticker_data.ps1_dxdt2

y = butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutOff, fs, order)
plt.plot(y)
```

I am very confused by this though because I am pretty sure the butter function takes in the cutoff and sampling frequency in rad/s but I seem to be getting a weird output. Is it actually in Hz?

Secondly, what is the purpose of these two lines:

```
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normalCutoff = cutOff / nyq
```

I know it's something about normalization but I thought the nyquist was 2 times the sampling requency, not one half. And why are you using the nyquist as a normalizer?

Can someone explain more about how to create filters with these functions?

I plotted the filter using:

```
w, h = signal.freqs(b, a)
plt.plot(w, 20 * np.log10(abs(h)))
plt.xscale('log')
plt.title('Butterworth filter frequency response')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [radians / second]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude [dB]')
plt.margins(0, 0.1)
plt.grid(which='both', axis='both')
plt.axvline(100, color='green') # cutoff frequency
plt.show()
```

and got this which clearly does not cut-off at 23 rad/s:

[image: result]

Answer (score 200, accepted):

A few comments:

- The [Nyquist frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) is half the sampling rate.
- You are working with regularly sampled data, so you want a digital filter, not an analog filter.  This means you should not use `analog=True` in the call to `butter`, and you should use `scipy.signal.freqz` (not `freqs`) to generate the frequency response.
- One goal of those short utility functions is to allow you to leave all your frequencies expressed in Hz.  You shouldn't have to convert to rad/sec.  As long as you express your frequencies with consistent units, the `fs` parameter of the SciPy functions will take care of the scaling for you.

Here's my modified version of your script, followed by the plot that it generates.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter, freqz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=5):
    return butter(order, cutoff, fs=fs, btype='low', analog=False)

def butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y


# Filter requirements.
order = 6
fs = 30.0       # sample rate, Hz
cutoff = 3.667  # desired cutoff frequency of the filter, Hz

# Get the filter coefficients so we can check its frequency response.
b, a = butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order)

# Plot the frequency response.
w, h = freqz(b, a, fs=fs, worN=8000)
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(w, np.abs(h), 'b')
plt.plot(cutoff, 0.5*np.sqrt(2), 'ko')
plt.axvline(cutoff, color='k')
plt.xlim(0, 0.5*fs)
plt.title("Lowpass Filter Frequency Response")
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.grid()


# Demonstrate the use of the filter.
# First make some data to be filtered.
T = 5.0         # seconds
n = int(T * fs) # total number of samples
t = np.linspace(0, T, n, endpoint=False)
# "Noisy" data.  We want to recover the 1.2 Hz signal from this.
data = np.sin(1.2*2*np.pi*t) + 1.5*np.cos(9*2*np.pi*t) + 0.5*np.sin(12.0*2*np.pi*t)

# Filter the data, and plot both the original and filtered signals.
y = butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(t, data, 'b-', label='data')
plt.plot(t, y, 'g-', linewidth=2, label='filtered data')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.35)
plt.show()
```

[image: lowpass example]

Comment: Thanks for the valuable advice! Are you sure the nyquist frequency is half the sampling frequency? I learned in my signals class that to fully reconstruct a signal from samples you need to sample at twice the bandwidth of the signal. Doesn't that mean the nyquist is twice the sampling frequency of the sensor?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  Consider the wording of "you need to sample at twice the bandwidth"; that says the *sample rate* must be twice the bandwidth of the signal.

Comment: In other words:  You are sampling at 30 Hz.  This means the bandwidth of your signal should not be more than 15 Hz; 15 Hz is the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: Im confused, if the bandwidth of my signal is 15Hz, why is the nyquist also that?

Is there any way to work with butter using rad/s?

Also i am getting this error when i try to use your code with some other data

`Digital filter critical frequencies must be 0 <= Wn <= 1`

But i am am normalizing it with the nyquist, so why would it be more than 1?

Comment: Re the error: that would occur if you used a `cutoff` value that was more than half of the sample rate `fs`; i.e. a `cutoff` that was more than the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: Re confusion: These comments aren't the best place for an explanation.  See if http://www.indiana.edu/~emusic/etext/digital_audio/chapter5_nyquist.shtml helps.  Also consider asking at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Resurrecting this: I saw in another [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13740532/209882) a suggestion to use filtfilt which performs backwards/forwards filtering instead of lfilter. What is your opinion on that?

Comment: @Bar: These comments aren't the right place to address your question.  You could create a new stackoverflow question, but the moderators might close it because it isn't a *programming* question.  The best place for it is probably http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: DSP question here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19084/applying-filter-in-scipy-signal-use-lfilter-or-filtfilt

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks for an awesome post. Might also be the wrong place to ask, but why did you set `worN=8000`? It seems like a random number in the context of the rest of the post.

Comment: @samjewell It's a random number that I seem to always use with `freqz`.  I like a *smooth* plot, with enough excess resolution that I can zoom in a bit without having to regenerate the plot, and 8000 is big enough to accomplish that in most cases.

Comment: it's interesting to read the 1st sentence of 2nd para in wikipedia's Nyquist Freq link given here. I was confused by this Nyquist Freq vs Nyquist rate as well.

Comment: This is quite a late comment, but one thing I noticed is that you didn't answer the part of the question that involved why you normalize your cut-off by the nyquist frequency. I'd also like to know the answer to that.