# Equivalent function in python for MATLAB's lowpass() function?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, lowpass-filter

I have the following code in matlab that applies a filter to the "data" dataset. I would like to find the equivalent function in python.

```matlab
epsilon = 8;
minpts = 12;
Normfreq = 0.0045;
Steepness = 0.9999;
StopbandAttenuation = 20;
filtered = lowpass(data, Normfreq, 'Steepness', Steepness, 'StopbandAttenuation', StopbandAttenuation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scipy is probably the best tool for this. You can use scipy's signal processing libraries.

From their [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html), they even offer matlab style filter desing.

> Matlab-style IIR filter design
>
> butter(N, Wn[, btype, analog, output, fs]) -Butterworth digital and analog filter design.
>
> buttord(wp, ws, gpass, gstop[, analog, fs]) - Butterworth filter order selection.
>
> cheby1(N, rp, Wn[, btype, analog, output, fs]) - 
>   Chebyshev type I digital and analog filter design.
>
> cheb1ord(wp, ws, gpass, gstop[, analog, fs]) -
>   Chebyshev type I filter order selection.
>
> cheby2(N, rs, Wn[, btype, analog, output, fs])- 
>   Chebyshev type II digital and analog filter design.
>
> cheb2ord(wp, ws, gpass, gstop[, analog, fs]) - 
>   Chebyshev type II filter order selection.
>
> ellip(N, rp, rs, Wn[, btype, analog, output, fs])- 
>   Elliptic (Cauer) digital and analog filter design.
>
> ellipord(wp, ws, gpass, gstop[, analog, fs])- 
>   Elliptic (Cauer) filter order selection.
>
> bessel(N, Wn[, btype, analog, output, norm, fs]) -
>   Bessel/Thomson digital and analog filter design.
>
> iirnotch(w0, Q[, fs]) -
>   Design second-order IIR notch digital filter.
>
> iirpeak(w0, Q[, fs]) -
>   Design second-order IIR peak (resonant) digital filter.

You'd probably want to use a [butterworth](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html#scipy.signal.butter) filter and then use the `lfilter` to apply the filter to your data.

Ref to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25191620/creating-lowpass-filter-in-scipy-understanding-methods-and-units) for a more in-depht example.