# Why does the file sound bad when gone through a filter in python

Tags: python, filter, scipy, signal-processing, python-sounddevice

When I try and filter a noisy file with a filter and try and play it again, it is just a mess. I found a solution that worked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60986056/audio-file-sounds-bad-noisy-after-passing-through-low-pass-filter), but why do i have to save it like this, and why cant i just play it in python, Can someone explain this?

Here is the code that i used.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as sg
from scipy.io import wavfile
import soundfile as sf
import sounddevice as sd
import pandas as pd

path = 'hammingfilter_1.csv'
b = np.genfromtxt(path, delimiter=',')
Fs, data = wavfile.read('pianoise.wav')
sd.play(data, blocking=True) #plays the sound
lfilt = sg.lfilter(b,1,data) #just tried to different ways, shouldnt matter much
y = sg.filtfilt(b,1,data)#
wavfile.write('LPF_filttered.wav', Fs, np.int16(y/np.max(np.abs(y)) * 32767)) # this is the solution im wondering about. This works and the sound is nice and filtered

sd.play(y,Fs,blocking=True)#this sounds totally shit
```

Comment: Could you please provide ```pianoise.wav```?

Comment: What is the type of y?

Comment: @Suthiro It is just a pianosound with som added noise. This happens to any sound I try to filter. Cant upload the file here.

Comment: @ThP it is a ndarray. See docs for scipy.signal.filtfilt for more info

Comment: @vegiv while it is just a pianosound, the file has format, bitrate and size, possibly relevant.

Comment: @Suthiro As shown in the code the pianosound is a wave file, with samplerate of 22050Hz, size of the file is 636kB.