# i want to make my plots smooth in python, how can i do it?

Tags: python, plot, smoothing

I have 600 files that each one contain The two columns  i, phase. I want to plot i in terms of phase, but my plots are not smooth. I want to write a code in python  that makes these 600 plots smoothly for me so that I can give them to CNN. I used the interpolation method  before but it didn't work
thank you for your help
[it is one of my plot that isn't smooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3oy6.png)

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25191620/1216776

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65964265/edit), and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with code, data, errors, current & expected output, as [formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)