# Downsampling of timeseries results in artificial flattening of the power spectral density. Should I first apply low pass filter?

Tags: python, pandas, signal-processing, data-analysis, downsampling

- Edit: I have tried to incoroporate @dankal444 script. Even though it does indeed remove the high frequencies as shown in the second figure, I still get a flatter spectrum at high frequencies in the downsampled timeseries.

I have been trying to estimate the power spectral density of a timeseries using fourier transform. I have a high resolution dataset and downsample it with linear interpolation to a lower cadence. However, this results in an artificial flattening of the power spectrum. Any idea why this happens?  Should I first apply low pass filter on the timeseries before downsampling?If so which one would be appropriate? Here is an example:

```
import datetime

# Ypou will need to ->  pip install fbm
from fbm import fbm

import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import butter, filtfilt


# Define functions
def TracePSD_2nd(x, dt):
    """ 
    Estimate Power spectral density:
    Inputs:
    u : timeseries, np.array
    dt: 1/sampling frequency
    """
    N = len(x)
    yf = np.fft.rfft(x)

    
    B_pow = abs(yf) ** 2 / N * dt

    freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(x), dt)
    freqs = freqs[freqs>0]
    idx   = np.argsort(freqs)
    
    return freqs[idx], B_pow[idx]

def butter_lowpass(f_cutoff, fs, order=5):
    return butter(order, f_cutoff, fs=fs, btype='low', analog=False)

def butter_lowpass_filter(data, dt, order=5):
    fs         = 1/dt
    f_nyquist  = fs / 2
    f_cutoff   = 0.999* f_nyquist
    b, a = butter_lowpass(f_cutoff, fs, order=order)
    if len(np.shape(data))>1:
        x   = filtfilt(b, a, data.T[0])
        y   = filtfilt(b, a, data.T[1])
        z   = filtfilt(b, a, data.T[2])
        res =  np.transpose(np.vstack((x,y,z)))
    else:
        res = filtfilt(b, a, data)
    return res

# User defined parameters

resolution      = 1000  # in miliseconds
init_resolution = 10    # in miliseconds

# create a sythetic timeseries using a fractional brownian motion !( In case you don't have fbm-> pip install fbm)
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

# Create index for timeseries
end_time  = datetime.datetime.now()+ pd.Timedelta('1H')
freq      = str(init_reolution)+'ms'
index = pd.date_range(
    start = start_time, 
    end = end_time, 
    freq = freq
)

# Generate a fBm realization
fbm_sample = fbm(n=len(index), hurst=0.75, length=1, method='daviesharte')


# Create a dataframe to resample the timeseries.
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': index, 'Br':fbm_sample[:-1]}).set_index('DateTime')



#Original version of timeseries
y = df_b.Br

# Apply filter
res = butter_lowpass_filter(y.values, dt=resolution*1e-3)

# Recreate dataframe after timeseries has been fitelered
df_b['Br'] = res  


# Resample the synthetic timeseries
x = df_b.Br.resample(str(int(resolution))+"ms").mean()


# Estimate the sampling rate
dtx  = (x.dropna().index.to_series().diff()/np.timedelta64(1, 's')).median()
dty  = (y.dropna().index.to_series().diff()/np.timedelta64(1, 's')).median()

# Estimate PSD using second method
resya = TracePSD_2nd(y, dty)
resxa = TracePSD_2nd(x, dtx)


plt.loglog(resya[0], resya[1], label ='Original timeseries')

plt.loglog(resxa[0], resxa[1], label ='Downsampled timeseries+ filter')


plt.legend()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you remove the parts of code that aren't necessary for the question ? we only see ax[1], therefore only the function and resya and resxa is needed as far as I can tell. For these two calculations it would be helpful if you could provide some sample of your  data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ok just made the changes you suggested! Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "artificial flattening of the power spectrum"? Green line is not more flat than the blue line

Comment: It is flatter at the highest frequencies right? At the same part of the spectrum the blue line is steeper. I think that this is caused by aliasing effect that I wanted to remove by applying some kind of low pass-filter but I am not sure how to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have been trying to estimate the power spectral density of a timeseries using fourier transform. I have a high resolution dataset and downsample it with linear interpolation to a lower cadence. However, this results in an artificial flattening of the power spectrum. Any idea why this happens?

This extra energy in high energy part is due to aliasing effect.

> Should I first apply low pass filter on the timeseries before downsampling?

Almost always. If you have any energy above new Nyquist frequency you need to do low-pass filtering or you will have aliasing effect. Only if there is no energy above Nyquist freq, there is no need to do filtering - there is nothing to filter out :)

> If so which one would be appropriate?

Generally, it is up to you how precise filtering you want to use. I would do with simple Butterworth, take a look [here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25192640/4601890).

EDIT: requested example of filtering:

```
# assuming you have some:
# - signal
# - cutoff (frequency)
# - fs (sampling frequency)

import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import butter, filtfilt

def butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=5):
    return butter(order, cutoff, fs=fs, btype='low', analog=False)

def butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_lowpass(cutoff, fs, order=order)
    y = filtfilt(b, a, data)
    return y

filtered_signal = butter_lowpass_filter(signal, cutoff, fs)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to reply. I am not familiar with this kind od filtering technique though. Does it introduce a phase shift in the data? It is important for me that the method used does not. Could you please incorporate an exampe to the code?

Comment: @Jokerp This method I linked will introduce phase shift. I edited it - changed it a bit - to remove the phase shift (by using `filtfilt` instead of `lfilter`)

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a rule of thumb for the cutoff frequency? given for example the resolution of the downsampled timeseries?

Comment: It can't be bigger than Nyquist frequency (=half of sampling rate). It is good though to make it a bit smaller than Nyquist frequency (95-98%), so you do not have to use high order, very steep filter.

Comment: thanks and sorry for asking again but you mean this? So if dt is the samling rate of the downampled timeseries the cutoff freq should be ~0.95*1/(2*dt)?

Comment: yes, but to be more elegant, I would do `fs = 1/dt`, then `f_cutoff = 0.95 * fs / 2`  or even add `f_nyquist = fs / 2` inbetween

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. I have modified the question because I still don't get the desired result. Would you mind taking a look? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm  maybe thats due to the fact that beginning of the time signal does not match the end of it. Fourier Transform "assumes" you provide a period of infinite signal - if it is not the case you need to either use [windowing](https://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/me451/me451_labs/Fall_2013/Understanding_FFT_Windows.pdf) or disregard those high frequencies (not analyse them or zero them)

Comment: putting the cutoff at 95% of Nyquist requires an aggressive filter, and is probably too close for this application.  85% or 90% would be more reasonable.  You should NOT expect a straight line down to the Nyquist frequency in the results.  You should be able to see the filter cutoff before *and after* downsampling.