# Low-pass Chebyshev type-I filter with Scipy

Tags: numpy, filter, scipy, signal-processing, data-processing

I am reading a paper, trying to reproduce the results of the paper. In this paper, they use a low-pass Chebyshev type-I filter on the raw data. And they give those parameters.

Sampling frequency = 32Hz, Fcut=0.25Hz, Apass = 0.001dB, Astop = -100dB, Fstop = 2Hz, Order of the filter = 5. I found some materials help me understand these parameters

[image]

But when I take a look at the scipy.signal.cheby1. The parameters required by this function are different.

```
cheby1(N, rp, Wn, btype='low', analog=False, output='ba')
```

Here N:The order of the filter; btype: type of filter, in my case, it is 'lowpass'; analog=False, because the data is sampled, so it is digital; output: specifies the type of output. But I am not sure about rp, Wn.

In the documentation, it says:

rp : float
The maximum ripple allowed below unity gain in the passband. Specified in decibels, as a positive number.

Wn : array_like
A scalar or length-2 sequence giving the critical frequencies. For Type I filters, this is the point in the transition band at which the gain first drops below -rp. For digital filters, Wn is normalized from 0 to 1, where 1 is the Nyquist frequency, pi radians/sample. (Wn is thus in half-cycles / sample.) For analog filters, Wn is an angular frequency (e.g. rad/s).

According to this question:
[How To apply a filter to a signal in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740348/how-to-apply-a-filter-to-a-signal-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I know how I can use the filter. But I don't know how to create a filter which has the same parameters as mentioned above. I don't know how to convert these parameters and provide them to the function in Scipy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [the wikipedia page on the Type I Chebyshev filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_filter#Type_I_Chebyshev_filters).  Note that your plot illustrates the characteristics of a general filter.  A lowpass Type I Chebyshev filter, however, has no ripple in the stop band.

You have three available parameters for the design of a Type I Chebyshev filter: the filter order, the ripple factor, and the cutoff frequency.  These are the first three parameters of [`scipy.signal.cheby1`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cheby1.html):

- The first argument of `cheby1` is the order of the filter.
- The second argument, `rp`, corresponds to δ in the wikipedia page, and is apparently what you called `Apass`.
- The third argument is `wn`, the cutoff frequency expressed as a fraction of the Nyquist frequency.  In your case, you could write something like

  ```
  fs = 32      # Sample rate (Hz)
  fcut = 0.25  # Desired filter cutoff frequency (Hz)

  # Cutoff frequency relative to the Nyquist
  wn = fcut / (0.5*fs)
  ```

Once those three parameters are chosen, all the other characteristics
(e.g. transition band width, Astop, Fstop, etc) are determined.  So it appears that the specification that you give, "Sampling frequency = 32Hz, Fcut=0.25Hz, Apass = 0.001dB, Astop = -100dB, Fstop = 2Hz, Order of the filter = 5", are not compatible with a Type I Chebyshev filter.  In particular, I get a gain of approximately -78 dB at 2 Hz.
(If you increase the order to 6, then the gain at 2 Hz is approximately -103.)

Here's a complete script, followed by the plot that it generates.  The plot shows just the pass band, but you can change the arguments of the `xlim` and `ylim` functions to see more.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import cheby1, freqz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Sampling parameters
fs = 32  # Hz

# Desired filter parameters
order = 5
Apass = 0.001  # dB
fcut = 0.25    # Hz

# Normalized frequency argument for cheby1
wn = fcut / (0.5*fs)

b, a = cheby1(order, Apass, wn)

w, h = freqz(b, a, worN=8000)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(0.5*fs*w/np.pi, 20*np.log10(np.abs(h)))
plt.axvline(fcut, color='r', alpha=0.2)
plt.plot([0, fcut], [-Apass, -Apass], color='r', alpha=0.2)
plt.xlim(0, 0.3)
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylim(-5*Apass, Apass)
plt.ylabel('Gain (dB)')
plt.grid()
plt.title("Chebyshev Type I Lowpass Filter")
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]